# Serializing type id in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have some template class:

```
template<class T>
class Foo
{
    void save(File& f);

    /* load */ Foo(const File& f);

    ...
}
```

I have a binary file format for Foo.  Foo::save saves to a file and the Foo(File) constructor loads it from a file.

When I save it I want to write the type of T in the header, and then when I load it I want to verify that the T used in the constructor is the same as that of the file.

How should I generate this type code?

(For example I could SHA the typeid(T).name().  However this can change between program invocations.  Is there a better way?)

Comment: Since you are coding save() and load(), put T in the code.  Have you looked at protocol-buffers from Google?

Comment: @brianbeuning: What do you mean "put T in the code"?

Comment: I missed the template part.  Never mind.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really an automatic, portable solution. The best I can think of is maintaining a manual list:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T> struct persistent_type_id; // unimplemented primary!

template <> struct persistent_type_id<MyClass>
: std::integral_constant<uint32_t, 0x12345678> { };

template <> struct persistent_type_id<AnotherClass>
: std::integral_constant<uint32_t, 0x12345679> { };

// ...
```

Usage:

```
persistent_type_id<T>::value
```

If you leave any type unimplemented, you'll get a compiler error right away.

Comment: Defining the same id for multiple types is unfortunate, but is possible with this solution

Comment: @Csq: Thanks - you can have a separate shell script to check the sanity of your IDs, I suppose.